# Why isn't my mouse working in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, mouse, hardware

For the past few weeks, my mouse has been not working properly in Ubuntu. At random, the mouse pointer freezes and not after any  amount of time does it work again. I can still tab around with the keyboard as much as possible, but when the mouse stop working, I have to at least restart my machine hard in order to get it to work again. Has happen after inactivity, light activity (1-2 windows open), moderate to heavy activity (using Krita and watching a video online), and after random times of 5 minutes to multiple hours.

As I type this, I just attempted to boot into Ubuntu and it didn't work at all.  I am currently typing this from a Windows boot on the same machine with the same keyboard and mouse.

I have looked this issue up in several places online and I hardly understand some of the troubleshooting procedures to take in order to fix or get a better understanding of the problem. I have been using Linux for while, but I never have luck getting help with issues as most of the time I either find the instruction too confusing or come across a jerk in the forums.

What issue am I having and how can I correct it?